# Automated Process in Apache Server with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, process, automation

I am saving dates to the my sql database.

i want to send a mail on that day.

how can i do that under this environment

Apache, Mysql, PHP

in windows xp we can do that it scheduled tasks or by creating Windows Server.

Anyone...

Cheers

Comment: @user658637: Are you using Linux? If yes, have a look at Cron jobs.

Comment: Check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707816/automated-e-mail-with-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running the apacheserver on Linux you can use [Crontabs](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).
Just create a PHP-script that does the interaction you want with the database, then add that as a crontab to make it run on a regular basis.

The reason I assume you're running Linux is because you already seems to have an idea on how to do it in windows.

Comment: THanks for the reply. Actually i am working in windows xp. But i have to host my site in linux server. That is why ask the question in that way.